# Why ionic splash screen does not hide?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

It hides only when minimize application (with home button) and open again (although in the chrome inspect it hidden)

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

way1:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

way2:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```